# How to check maximum memory I can request for a pod in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, memory, nodes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I am using an EKS cluster with 4 nodes. There are multiple applications running in the kubernetes cluster(nearly 30-40 pods) with different cpu and memory requests.

Now I wish to increase the memory of one particular pod, now how to choose what maximum memory I can assign to the pod in my cluster.

My Idea is to get the free memory inside the kubernetes nodes and based on that will decide the maximum memory that I can assign to pod.

I am trying with free command in pods to check the memory available.

How can I get the free memory available in my EKS cluster nodes?

Note: There is no metrics server installed in my EKS cluster

Answer (score 2):

There may be namespace specific limits, which could be lower than whats available at the node level. In this case, you will have to consider the namespace limits.

However, if thats not the case, as a starting value, you may the below command and look at the "Requests" column and choose the request value in your pod that is lower than the available amount shown for your most utilized node.

```
kubectl get node --no-headers | while read node status; do echo '>>>>  ['$node']'; kubectl describe node $node | grep Resource -A 3 ;done
>>>>  [node-be-worker-1]
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                300m (7%)   100m (2%)
  memory             220Mi (2%)  220Mi (2%)
>>>>  [node-be-worker-2]
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                200m (5%)   100m (2%)
  memory             150Mi (1%)  50Mi (0%)
>>>>  [node-be-worker-3]
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                400m (10%)  2100m (52%)
  memory             420Mi (5%)  420Mi (5%)
>>>>  [node-master-0]
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                650m (32%)  100m (5%)
  memory             50Mi (1%)   50Mi (1%)
```

Explanation: The command lists all the nodes and loops over to describe the nodes and then filters the lines for "Resource" and prints the string and the next 3 lines.

You should be able to tweak the above command to work for namespace too.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Wanna understand the command once, and other thing , so the values shown in Requests section are available memory in nodes?? Is it??? Can I choose a value among those values shown in Requests????
Pls help on this as this is a critical for me

Comment: Request gives you the current utilization. So, 10% = 400m in above example shows that on that node, you have 3600m remaining. So, if you chose your container to have anything less than 3600m, kubernetes will be able to schedule it on that node (node-be-worker-3), provided no other pod consumed more resources since the time the command was run. Limits is the max a container will get

Comment: @Balakrishna I have added the explanation to the command in my post. Please review

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, Another small question is the requests section is the current utilization right, but the pod might have additional memory assigned but it is using lets say half of memory allocated, If I have to get the maximum memory limits defined for all pods running in a pod irrespective of what is the current utilization then in that case I need to check the limits column..???

Is that correct??

Comment: I want the memory free in a node after all pods memory limits that are already present in the cluster

Comment: Here , Take my case ``` Resource Requests Limits -------- -------- ------ cpu 2510m (64%) 2 (51%) memory 8650Mi (58%) 8880Mi (59%) From the above, my current pods can utilize max of 8880M (i.e 59%) , I am using an instance with 16Gi of memory, How much free memory is available in my current node (assuming my limt reaches max)

Comment: The problem with basing your decision on limit is that total limit could be > 100%. So, it will not give you the precise picture. (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)